# Por que o servidor não recebe meus dados corretamente?

Tags: php, echo

```
<htlm>
<head>

<title>Horta do Bob - Resultado da compra </title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Horta do Bob </h1>
<h2> Resultado da compra </h2>

<?php

//cria nomes de variável abreviados
$Salameqty = $_POST['Salameqty'];
$Manjericãoqty = $_POST['Manjericãoqty'];
$Abobrinhaqty = $_POST['Abobrinhaqty'];

 echo '<p>Resultado processado em ';
 echo date('H:i, jS F');
  echo '</p>';

echo '<p>Confira seu pedido: </p>';

echo $Salameqty.' Salames<br />';
echo $Manjericãoqty.' Manjericões<br />';
echo $Abobrinhaqty.' Abobrinhas<br />';


?>

</body>
</head>
```

No servidor, ele só reconhece o primeiro pedido. Os números dos outros pedidos não aparecem. Eu já chequei de tudo, o que pode ser?

------Código do formulário (Disfarcem a simplicidade)

```
<form action="processorder.php" method=post>
<table border=5>
<tr bgcolor=#0091C9>
 <td width=100>Lanche</td>
 <td width=100>Quantos?</td>
</tr>

 <tr>
 <td>Salame</td>
 <td align="center"><input type="text" name="Salameqty" size"2" maxlenght="5"></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td>Manjericão</td>
 <td align="center"><input type="text" name="Manjericãoqty size"2" maxlenght="2"></td>  
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td>Abobrinha</td>
 <td align="center"><input type="text" name="Abobrinhaqty size"2" maxlenght=2"></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Processar pedido">
 </td>
```

Comment: Coloque o código completo...

Comment: Coloquei. O resto do código tá firmeza, até reconhece a data e hora, mas os pedidos...

Comment: Veja se o atributo `name` dos inputs não está diferente dos resgatos pelo `$_POST`

Comment: Pior que não! Até por que quando eu clico no nome, o Notepad faz a relação direta.

Comment: Coloque o código do formulário

Comment: Código adicionado

Comment: Estou votando para fechar por erro de digitação, desde o começo da tag `<htlm>` que não existe, até os nomes dos campos, valores e atributos escritos errados. Sugiro no mínimo ter um pouco de atenção ao digitar antes de trazer o código para cá, economizando o tempo dos colegas. Você é super bem-vindo para tirar suas dúvidas de programação aqui, e queremos ajudar, mas antes é necessário que você capriche um pouco mais, para seu próprio treino, e aproveitamento melhor do conhecimento dos colegas, conseguindo mais autonomia para programar, e melhores resultados aqui.

Comment: Eu não costumo comentar quando negativo, mas vou abrir uma exceção: Eu negativei sua pergunta justamente pelo que o Bacco citou acima, parece que você teve  muita desatenção no seu código, e essa pergunta dificilmente poderá ajudar alguém resolver um problema real (por se tratar de um erro de digitação). Por isso o negativo. Entenda que não estou negativando "sua pessoa", mas sim o conteúdo. Os votos são  um qualitativo para avaliar se a pergunta é boa ou não. Ok?

Comment: Não pô, pode negativar! Eu que fui burro mesmo. Eu tô começando a sacar o nível das coisas por aqui, e prometo que um problema besta desse não virá a se repetir aqui, obrigado!

Comment: @Caio que bom que você não levou para o lado pessoal, isso é muito importante pra tudo na vida. Capriche do seu lado aí, que do nosso a gente vai fazer o possível para te ajudar quando você precisar. E com o tempo, suas dúvidas e postagens naturalmente vão melhorar, e junto com isso a pontuação também. Aqui tem umas dicas legais a hora que tiver um tempinho pra ler: [Ask] e [Help]. E seja bem-vindo à rede! Fique tranquilo, que levar uma "chacoalhada" da comunidade nas primeiras perguntas é super normal :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No servidor, ele só reconhece o primeiro pedido. Os números dos outros pedidos não aparecem. Eu já chequei de tudo, o que pode ser?

Respondendo à sua pergunta: Isso aqui está errado:

```
 <input type="text" name="Abobrinhaqty size"2" maxlenght=2">
```

O certo é isso aqui:

```
<input type="text" name="Abobrinhaqty" size="2" maxlength=2">
```

Você esqueceu de fechar as aspas. Se não botar os nomes corretamente, o `formulário` não enviará os dados corretamente para o servidor. Além do mais, você esqueceu de colocar o sinal de `=` em alguns atributos.

É esse o erro no seu código. O primeiro está aparecendo na resposta do servidor porque ele foi declarado corretamente (pelo menos o campo `name` está certo).

```
 <input type="text" name="Salameqty" size"2" maxlenght="5">
```

Ainda sim há outro erro nos outros atributos, que é no atributo `size`, que deveria ser `size="2"` (esqueceu do sinal de `=`).

Comment: cara alem desse erro ele nao ta fazendo nenhum while ou for para retornar o array dos pedidos, eu acho q ta faltando cod ai

Comment: Caraca, que erro besta! Não sei como eu não vi essas aspas faltando, muito obrigado! E Jasar, eu ainda não terminei o código, eu tava travado nessa parte. Acho que é o notepad que tá comendo as minhas linhas quando eu substituo alguma coisa, mas mesmo assim, valeu!

Comment: Não são as aspas é o sinal de `=`...